# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v4.content.Loader

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-loadermanager

I want to implement `LoaderManager` in my application in order to reduce the startup time [As you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767014/how-to-make-the-android-app-load-faster) but after implementing the suggestion in that thread i was getting the following error `initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, MainActivity)`. After searching on here i found the solution for that second error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918397/initializing-a-loader-in-an-activity). But after implementing the suggestion from later, now i am getting the error `java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.content.Loader`. I am putting up the code which i currently have, can anyone tell me, how can i solve this problem

**FULL CODE CAN BE SEEN** [HERE](http://pastebin.com/gNa3jcYW)

**Log Cat**

```
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.sms.it/com.test.sms.it.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.support.v4.content.Loader.<init>(Loader.java:91)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.<init>(AsyncTaskLoader.java:92)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at com.test.sms.it.MainActivity$ContactsDataLoader.<init>(MainActivity.java:104)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at com.test.sms.it.MainActivity.onCreateLoader(MainActivity.java:496)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:487)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:496)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:550)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at com.test.sms.it.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-03 20:11:34.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editUser1UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser1UserName);
    editUser1Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser1Password);
    editUser2UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser2UserName);
    editUser2Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser2Password);
    editUser3UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser3UserName);
    editUser3Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser3Password);
    editUser4UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser4UserName);
    editUser4Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser4Password);
    editUser5UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser5UserName);
    editUser5Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser5Password);
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
    mTxtPhoneNo.setThreshold(1);
    mTxtPhoneNo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGateway);
    btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnsend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnContact.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    readPerson();
    Panel panel;
    topPanel = panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.mytopPanel);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator(Type.OUT));
    getLoginDetails();
}

public class ContactsDataLoader extends
        AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> {
    public ContactsDataLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> loadInBackground() {
        mPeopleList.clear();
        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                null);
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            String contactName = people
                    .getString(people
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = people
                    .getString(people
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String numberType = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                    if (numberType.equals("0"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                    else if (numberType.equals("1"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                    else if (numberType.equals("2"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Mobile");
                    else
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");
                    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
        people.close();
        startManagingCursor(people);
        return mPeopleList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        forceLoad();
    }
}

public Loader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> onCreateLoader(int id,
        Bundle args) {
    return new ContactsDataLoader(context);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> loader,
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data) {
    mPeopleList = data;
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
            new String[] { "Name", "Phone", "Type" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> loader) {
    mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
            new String[] { "Name", "Phone", "Type" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Check 104 line. There is something null there.

Comment: have you checked arrays or any other data type ? because it is crashing due to null pointer exception, Sorry I don;t have much time to review your code.

Comment: @Dharmendra at line 104 this code is there `super(context);`

Comment: @Mudasar i didnt get what you are trying to say..

Comment: In public Loader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> onCreateLoader(int id,
        Bundle args) {
    return new ContactsDataLoader(context);
}
Where are you getting context ?

Comment: @Dharmendra in the constructor of `ContactsDataLoader` see this `public ContactsDataLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
`

Comment: @Dharmendra i told u. I am getting `Context`  in the constructor of `ContactsDataLoader` class

Comment: You did not answer the question.  The question is where do you get the context from, not how do you use it.  You do not "get" a context in a constructor, you use it.  I can't see where you are getting the context from in your code.  If you put a breakpoint on that line, is context null?

Comment: That I am telling but @TapanDesai is not getting my point.

Comment: I assume `context` is null here: `new ContactsDataLoader(context);`

Comment: @Dharmendra yes you are right. The value is not been assigned to `context`. What value should be assigned? Full code can be seen here --> http://pastebin.com/gNa3jcYW

Comment: @RC. what's the solution then? Yes null is exactly where you pointed out

Comment: Create a field of Context in your class and assign the context which you are getting in the constructor and then use that context to create the object of ContactsDataLoader class

Comment: @Dharmendra can you please paste a code snippet. I am very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RC`'s comment is the answer of your problem. You pass a `null` `Context`(as I don't see anywhere in the code you posted the `context` variable being initialized with a valid reference) to your custom loader and the code will fail with a `NullPointerException`. If you used my code from my previous answer then those callbacks are implemented in your `Activity`. In this case just pass `this`, the reference to your current `Activity` instance, to your custom loader:

```
public Loader<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> onCreateLoader(int id,
        Bundle args) {
    return new ContactsDataLoader(this);
}
```

Also, if you close the cursor, there is no need to use `startManagingCursor()` for that `Cursor` as you might get in trouble.

Comment: now it says `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner member class: ContactsDataLoader android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)`

Comment: @TapanDesai The exception is pretty clear, the `ContactsDataLoader` class can't be a non static element in your activity. Make `mPeopleList` static and also add the `static` keyword for your `ContactsDataLoader` class `public class ContactsDataLoader...`. Although, another use of the `ContactsDataLoader` might be recommended.

Comment: i cannot add `static` keyword to the class `ContactsDataLoader` as it contains `getContentResolver()` which will give me error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContentResolver() from the type ContextWrapper`

Comment: @TapanDesai In the constructor of the `ContactsDataLoader` you have a reference to the outer activity(the `context`). Cast it to an `Activity` and then call the `getContentResolver` method on it(make it a field in your `ContactsDataLoader` class). Like this : `((Activity) context).getContentResolver()...` , then you can make it `static`.

Comment: if you have noticed i my `MainActivity extends FragementActivity` so does that mean i should use something like this? `((FragementActivity) context).getContentResolver()`

Comment: @TapanDesai It doesn't matter `FragmentActivity` extends `Activity` anyway. Just try any of them.

Comment: i tried casting it to `FragementActivity` and it worked but now another error. I have pasted log cat here ---> http://pastebin.com/RsdcVsDK